# Building a Jobs page, should I go with a list display or slider?

Tags: lists, sliders, carousel

I'm wondering which would be the better route from a usability perspective to take as I've had some disagreement with a colleague of mine.

We are trying to build a Jobs page which will list all of the jobs in our organisation. The jobs are categorised so we decided it best to have buttons for each department and populate the jobs section based on the department chosen.

Here's where the disagreement occurred.

I thought it's best to have a list of the job titles and an apply button beside each one. However, my colleague figured it would be best to have a slider of all the jobs in the category which I personally dislike very much.

The thing I'm concerned with is if we potentially have 20 jobs in a department and the user has to slide through every single one of them then I think it would be very frustrating. Whereas I know a list is not ideal but at least the information is displayed in an easy to read, clean manner.

I'm wondering what the community thinks, are lists better than sliders in this case? I know it depends on the situation entirely but I also heard sliders are a bad idea if you've more than 3 - 4 slides.

Comment: How would the implementation with the slider work? Maybe you could include a mockup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only advantage of a slider over next/previous navigation is the possibility to jump (seemingly) freely to any index. In reality this would hardly work, as the user cannot distinguish the individual index locations and needs to hunt for the right position, even if they remember the general direction. Thus, I'd classify the slider the same as indexable navigation.

The list with all positions shows much more relevant data to the user at once. As the user is trying to find a best suitable position for them, they essentially need to *compare* the various positions. This is really hard if only one is visible at a time.

A good way to test different ideas is to have a real use case and simulate using the UI *as the real user would do*.

When they have to navigate positions one by one, they don't know what the ideal position for them would be until they have looked at each of them. The list is much faster to skim through, and even if it only had the basic information, the user can much faster get to comparing the most prominent positions.

Comment: Hey Jawa, I never even thought of the user needing to compare the different positions and your 110% correct on that. I will bring this up later today when I talk with my colleagues. Your answer was incredibly helpful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Go with a list. This is a job *listing* page and the slider will infuriate people as they'll want to scan information quickly to pick out the job titles that suit them.

A compromise might be to have a featured jobs slider with 3 or so featured jobs at the top of the page? That might satisfy your colleague but mean that the bulk of the information is easily digestible :)

Comment: +1 for the featured jobs idea. I think that might definitely be a good compromise. Thanks for your input Chris, it was very helpful .

Comment: no worries, good luck!